# UIStackview not resizing inside stackview embedded in scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a child `UIStackView` that is embedded inside another parent `UIStackView`, the parent `UIStackView` is embedded in a `UIScrollView` since we need to add a lot of views, whenever the child `UIStackview` height shrinks, It doesn't reflect in the parent `UIStackView` and it maintains the old height.

This is the hierarchy of the parent view

[hierarchy of the parent view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqRkf.png)

Code for parent `UIStackView`

```
func displayViews(_ views: [childrenViews]) {
    stackView.removeSubviews()
    childrenViews.forEach {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Code for Child `UIStackView`

```
func displayLoadedViews(viewModels: [ViewModel]) {
    mainVerticalStackView.removeSubviews()
    viewModels.enumerated().forEach { (index, item) in
        let view = View()
        mainVerticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
    }
}
```

This is screenshot for `UIScrollView` Constraints in the parent view, this `UISCrollView` is holding the parent `UIStackView`

[Scrollview Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYc3S.png)

Comment: Can you share some code example? You might just need to render the relevant cell

Comment: @CloudBalancing I have edited the question to contain code sample. Let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: Where do you calculate the scrollView size?

Comment: @CloudBalancing via the xib constraints, I attached a screenshot in the question with the constraints of the `UIScrollView`